# Mocha mocking class method include before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocha.js

I'm trying to test that `before_filter` is being called from a concern. My test looks like this:

```
class AuthorizableController < ApplicationController
  include Authorizable
end

describe Authorizable do
  let(:dummy) { AuthorizableController.new }

  it "adds a before filter to the class" do
    AuthorizableController.expects(:before_filter).with(:authorize)

    dummy.class_eval do |klass|
      include Authorizable
    end
  end
end
```

My concern looks like so:

```
module Authorizable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :authorize
  end
end
```

...and I'm getting an error that looks like this (no mention of mocha, and instead MiniTest, when I'm using RSpec...):

```
Failures:

  1) Authorizable adds a before filter to the class
     Failure/Error: AuthorizableController.expects(:before_filter).with(:authorize)
     MiniTest::Assertion:
       not all expectations were satisfied
       unsatisfied expectations:
       - expected exactly once, not yet invoked: AuthorizableController.before_filter(:authorize)
     # ./spec/controllers/concerns/authorizable_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rails method `class_eval` evaluates on the singleton class of the object in question not the concrete class. There's more of an explanation in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212407/what-exactly-is-the-singleton-class-in-ruby) of what a singleton class is. Because the filter is being added to that singleton class your expectation of `authorize` being called on the main class isn't met.

You could add the expectation on the singleton class for `dummy`:

```
dummy.singleton_class.expects(:before_filter).with(:authorize)
```