# RSpec custom matchers syntax. What is going on structurally?

Tags: ruby

From the RSpec docs:

```
require 'rspec/expectations'

RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_multiple_of do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual % expected == 0
  end
end

RSpec.describe 9 do
  it { is_expected.to be_a_multiple_of(3) }
end
```

What is going on here? When defining a matcher what is this section of code:

```
:be_a_multiple_of do |expected|
      match do |actual|
        actual % expected == 0
      end
    end
```

Is that a `Proc`? What is being passed to the `.define` method? What is `|expected|`? Is that the 3 that we pass into the method? How does `:be_a_multiple_of` become a method? There seems to be a lot of metaprogrammy magic going on so I'd like to just figure out what is happening.

What is this `match do` method?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? On the one hand, you ask about metaprogramming, but on the other hand, it also appears that you lack the basic fundamentals of Ruby syntax. So, what is your question exactly? Is it about RSpec Matchers? Is it about metaprogramming? (In which case it is probably a duplicate of a question that has already been asked and answered.) Is it about basic Ruby syntax? (In that case, it is *definitely* a dupilcate.)

Comment: Can you clarify what is going on here?

Comment: The "section of code" you ask about isn't even syntactically valid Ruby. You need to clarify your question. Do you want an explanation of Ruby syntax? Of Ruby metaprogramming? Of RSpec? See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253894/2988 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278797/2988

Comment: But I copied it from the RSpec docs....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the rspec source docs for starters - http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers/DSL/Matcher

if you wanted to make a method callable like this:

```
some_method :symbol do
end

# one-liner version (parens are needed for arg)
some_method(:symbol) { }
```

you could define this:

```
def some_method(arg, &block)
  # the block gets called in here
end
```

See [Blocks and yields in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066703/blocks-and-yields-in-ruby)

As far as the symbol being turned into a method - this is actually pretty common, and is one of the main things that distinguishes symbols from strings.

So on that RSpec doc page, it says:

> The block passed to RSpec::Matchers.define will be evaluated in the context of the singleton class of an instance, and will have the Macros methods available.

If you want to see exactly what's going on here you can go through the RSpec source code. However the internals aren't necessarily as well documented,

See [What exactly is the singleton class in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212407/what-exactly-is-the-singleton-class-in-ruby)