# Rspec - Testing a class method which invokes module method by the Class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to write rspec test to verify a class method which invokes the included module method by the class name. When I call the module method using the Module name it works fine, but throws NoMethodError when invoked by class name.

```
module Test
  def self.module_mtd
    p "test"
  end
end

class Burger 
  include Test

  attr_reader :options

  def initialize(options={})
    @options = options
  end

  def apply_ketchup
    @ketchup = @options[:ketchup]
  end

  def has_ketchup_on_it?
    Burger.module_mtd # Throws NoMethodError
    Test.module_mtd #Works fine as expected
    @ketchup
  end
end


describe Burger do
  describe "#apply_ketchup" do
    subject { burger }
    before  { burger.apply_ketchup }

    context "with ketchup" do
      let(:burger) { Burger.new(:ketchup => true) }

      it { should have_ketchup_on_it }
    end

    context "without ketchup" do
      let(:burger) { Burger.new(:ketchup => false) }

      it { should_not have_ketchup_on_it }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `include Test` should be on its own line. A class declaration should only look like `class Foo` or `class Foo < Bar`. I'm kind of suprised that its not a syntax error (its still pretty bad style though).

Comment: I usually follow that convention. Just was in a hurry to post the question. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the test itself but your understanding of how class methods work in Ruby.

```
module Test
  def self.module_mtd
    p "test"
  end
end
```

Declares a method belonging to `Test`. Unlike the modules instance methods this is not added to the class when you include the module.

To declare a class method from a module you need to use the module mixins pattern to extend the singleton class:

```
module Test
  # this is called when you include the module
  def self.included(base)
    # this adds the class methods to the class
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def foo
      puts "hello world"
    end
  end
end
```

The fact that `module ClassMethods` declares `foo` as an instance method can seem kind of confusing until you realize that the singleton class that you are extending is an instance of "Class".

See:

- [What exactly is the singleton class in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212407/what-exactly-is-the-singleton-class-in-ruby)
- [Ruby Modules and Mixins](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm)
- [ActiveSupport::Concern - sugar coats this pattern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

Comment: Thanks! It worked fine.