# In Ruby, how do you write a simple method that can be used with &:symbol?

Tags: ruby, proc

This [article](https://blog.pjam.me/posts/ruby-symbol-to-proc-the-short-version/) touches on the issues but doesn't give a solution.

This started when I wanted to write a method and optionally pass it an argument which could be null or a `????` (`proc`, `lambda`, `method`, `block`, ???).  Lets call it, for now, a `block` because a `block` works.  The `block` takes one required argument.  An example of the method and a call to it would be:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def foo(&proc)
  puts "before"
  if proc
    yield "passed to proc"
  end
  puts "after"
end

def add_message(s)
  puts "from add_message #{s}"
end

foo { |s| add_message(s) }
foo
```

And the output is:

```
before
from add_message passed to proc
after
before
after
```

Great.  But, what I'd like to do is be able to call `foo` like this: `foo(&:add_message)`.  But I can't.  Changing line 15 above I get:

```
before
./temp.rb:11:in `add_message': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
    from ./temp.rb:6:in `foo'
    from ./temp.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

And, as the article above mentions, the arity is now -2.  So, how do I write a simple method like `add_message` that I can use with `&:add_message`.  OR!!! as is the case 99.99% of the time, please set me on the proper track on how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Symbol#to_proc` does not create a proc that calls `add_message` method correctly.

```
# `yield` will pass its arguments to proc
>> :add_message.to_proc.call('passed to proc')
# => ArgumentError
```

This calls `'passed to proc'.add_message`, because our method is defined in `Object` it works when called on `String`, however it is missing the required argument.

The solution is to make a proc that can accept the same arguments as `add_message` method and pass them along to that method. We can use `Object#method` that returns `Method` object that implements its own `to_proc` and has the same arity as the method.

```
>> method(:add_message).to_proc.arity
=> 1

>> method(:add_message).to_proc.call('passed to proc')
from add_message passed to proc
```

```
>> foo(&method(:add_message))
before
from add_message passed to proc
after
```

Comment: _"The problem is arity"_ – that's what Ruby complains about, but I think the larger problem is a mismatch between receiver, message and argument. `foo(&method(:add_message))` results in `add_message("passed to proc")` whereas `foo(&:add_message)` results in `"passed to proc".add_message`.

Answer (score 3):

From [the Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Proc.html#class-Proc-label-Conversion+of+other+objects+to+procs)

> ## Conversion of other objects to procs
>
> Any object that implements the `to_proc` method can be converted into a proc by the `&` operator, and therefore can be consumed by iterators.
>
> ```rb
> class Greeter
>   def initialize(greeting)
>     @greeting = greeting
>   end
>
>   def to_proc
>     proc {|name| "#{@greeting}, #{name}!" }
>   end
> end
>
> hi = Greeter.new("Hi")
> hey = Greeter.new("Hey")
> ["Bob", "Jane"].map(&hi)    #=> ["Hi, Bob!", "Hi, Jane!"]
> ["Bob", "Jane"].map(&hey)   #=> ["Hey, Bob!", "Hey, Jane!"]
> ```
>
> Of the Ruby core classes, this method is implemented by `Symbol`, `Method`, and `Hash`.

So when you pass an argument with a unary ampersand before it, `to_proc` gets called on it. The `&:` "syntax" is actually `&` being called on a symbol literal, i.e. `&(:foobar)`, and `Symbol.to_proc` has the behavior of converting a symbol into a method call on its first argument, i.e. these two are roughly equivalent (modulo named argument forwarding)

```
:foobar.to_proc
proc { |x, *args| x.foobar(*args) }
```

Ruby's `Method` type also implements `to_proc`, so if you have a standalone method called `foobar` (on a module, say, `Example`), then you can call `Example.method(:foobar)` and get an `&`-compatible object. If you have a "top-level" method, then it's probably [being defined on the `main` object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51596491/2288659) and calling `method` with no explicit receiver will work.

The other type mentioned in that quote is hashes, which can be turned into a function mapping their keys to their values (and returning `nil` if no matching key exists). And, of course, you can always implement a method called `to_proc` on your own classes and it'll work just as well as any built-in type.

Comment: Calling `method` without a receiver also works if the method belongs to the current `self`, e.g. when calling `method` from within an instance method to refer to another instance method (of the same object).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Integer
    def set
        return self + 1
    end
end

p [1,2,3,4,5,6].map(&:set)
```

I think when you can use `&:` syntax that a method have been defined for a class like above

Comment: Yes.  `&:foo` means `{ |x| x.foo(args) }`.  I'm doing something completely different -- `{ |x| foo(x) }`