# How to Make Or Reference a Null Ruby Binding For Eval

Tags: ruby, eval

Rubocop dislikes the following; it issues `Pass a binding, __FILE__ and __LINE__ to` eval`.`:

```rb
sort_lambda = eval "->(a) { a.date }"
```

Yes, I know that `eval` is a security problem. The issue of security is out of scope for this question.

The [Ruby documentation on binding](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Binding.html) says:

> Objects of class `Binding` encapsulate the execution context at some particular place in the code and retain this context for future use. The variables, methods, value of `self`, and possibly an iterator block that can be accessed in this context are all retained. Binding objects can be created using `Kernel#binding`, and are made available to the callback of `Kernel#set_trace_func` and instances of `TracePoint`.

> These binding objects can be passed as the second argument of the `Kernel#eval method`, establishing an environment for the evaluation.

The lambda being created does not need to access any variables in any scopes.
A quick and dirty binding to the scope where the `eval` is invoked from would look like this:

```rb
sort_lambda = eval "->(a) { a.date }", self.binding, __FILE__, __LINE__
```

Ideally, a null binding (a binding without anything defined in it, nothing from `self`, etc.) should be passed to this `eval` instead.
How could this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly, but you can approximate it.

Before I go further, I know you've already said this, but I want to emphasize it for future readers of this question as well. **What I'm describing below is NOT a sandbox.** This will NOT protect you from malicious users. If you pass user input to `eval`, it can still do a lot of damage with the binding I show you below. Consult a cybersecurity expert before trying this in production.

Great, with that out of the way, let's move on. You can't really have an empty binding in Ruby. The [`Binding`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Binding.html) class is sort of compile-time magic. Although the class proper only exposes a way to get *local* variables, it also captures any constant names (including class names) that are in scope at the time, as well as the current receiver object `self` and all methods on `self` that can be invoked from the point of execution. The problem with an empty binding is that Ruby is a lot like Smalltalk sometimes. Everything exists in one big world of Platonic ideals called "objects", and no Ruby code can truly run in isolation.

In fact, trying to do so is really just putting up obstacles and awkward goalposts. Think you can block me from accessing `BasicObject`? If I have literally any object `a` in Ruby, then `a.class.ancestors.last` is `BasicObject`. Using this technique, we can get any global class by simply having an instance of that class or a subclass. Once we have classes, we have modules, and once we have modules we have [`Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Kernel.html), and at that point we have most of the Ruby built-in functionality.

Likewise, `self` always exists. You can't get rid of it. It's a fundamental part of the Ruby object system, and it exists even in situations where you don't think it does (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51565909/what-are-the-rules-for-self-in-a-top-level-method) of mine from awhile back, for instance). *Every* method or block of code in Ruby has a receiver, so the most you can do is try to limit the receiver to be as small an object as possible. One might think you want `self` to be [`BasicObject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/BasicObject.html), but amusingly there's not really a way to do that either, since you can only *get* a binding if [`Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Kernel.html) is in scope, and `BasicObject` doesn't include `Kernel`. So at minimum, you're getting all of `Kernel`. You might be able to skimp by somehow and use some subclass of `BasicObject` that includes `Kernel`, thereby avoiding other `Object` methods, but that's likely to cause confusion down the road too.

All of this is to emphasize that a hypothetical null binding would really only make it slightly more complicated to get all of the global names, not impossible. And that's why it doesn't exist.

That being said, if your goal is to eliminate *local* variables and to try, you can get that easily by creating a binding inside of a module.

```
module F
  module_function def get_binding
    binding
  end
end

sort_lambda = eval "->(a) { a.date }", F.get_binding
```

This binding will never have local variables, and the methods and constants it has access to are limited to those available in `Kernel` or at the global scope. That's about as close to "null" as you're going to get in the complex nexus of interconnected types and names we call Ruby.

Comment: Terrific answer, thanks. It might be better to name the `module_function` something like `min_binding`. ALso, appending `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` would make Rubocop happy. `eval "->(a) { a.date }", MinimalBinding.min_binding, __FILE__, __LINE__`

Answer (score 3):

While I originally left this as a comment on [@Silvio Mayolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2288659/silvio-mayolo)'s answer, which is very well written, it seems germane to post it as an answer instead.

While most of what is contained within that answer is correct we can get slightly closer to a *"Null Binding"* through `BasicObject` inheritance:

```
class NullBinding < BasicObject 
  def get_binding 
    ::Kernel
      .instance_method(:binding)
      .bind(self)
      .call
  end
end
```

This binding context has as limited a context as possible in ruby.

Using this context you will be unable to reference constants solely by name:

```
eval 'Class', NullBinding.new.get_binding 
#=> NameError
```

That being said you can still reference the TOP_LEVEL scope so

```
eval '::Class', NullBinding.new.get_binding 
#=> Class
```

The methods *directly* available in this binding context are limited only to the instance methods available to [BasicObject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/BasicObject.html). By way of Example:

```
eval "puts 'name'", NullBinding.new.get_binding 
#=> NoMethodError
```

Again with the caveat that you can access TOP_LEVEL scope so:

```
eval "::Kernel.puts 'name'", NullBinding.new.get_binding 
# name
#=> nil
```