# Include a module on instances instead of a class

Tags: ruby

I have a module:

```
module MM::NN
  def test_method
    puts "module method called"
  end
end
```

I am trying to include this module in a class `A` per instance depending on a parameter passed to the initializer of the instance:

```
class A
  def initialize(add_module)
    self.class.send(:include, MM::NN) if add_module
  end
end
```

I expected:

```
A.new(true).test_method  # >> module method called
A.new(false).test_method  # >> NoMethodError
```

But `test_method` is defined on all instances. Calling the class with argument `true` adds the module to the instances created later as well. I got:

```
A.new(true).test_method  # >> module method called
A.new(false).test_method  # >> NoMethodError
```

Initializing the class with `false` argument on first initializer call and `true` in the second will give the desired result, as `test_method` method is added later:

```
A.new(false).test_method  # >> NoMethodError
A.new(true).test_method  # >> module method called
```

because the module is attached to the class itself.

How can I make the method available on specific cases like above?

How do i solve an another case:
where `class A` inherit properties and methods of another `class B` and `class B` as well contains `test_method`. How is it possible to use the module `TestModule`s `test_method` instead of method inside the `class B`.

And what are the differences(or)side-effects in calling methods by including a module inside a class:
1) include module outside initialize.
2) Include module inside initialize.

Comment: "keep a module included" makes no sense. Once included you can't un-include a module. Are you saying you want only instances for which `add_module` is `true` to respond to the instance methods in the module? If so, you need to say that.

Comment: I don't see any difference between your expected result and the result you got.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `self.class.send(:include, MM::NN)`, that's making a irreversible change to the *class* (the blueprint for all instances).

If you want a module to only be included for an instance, you have to use the singleton class ([What exactly is the singleton class in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212407/what-exactly-is-the-singleton-class-in-ruby)):

```
module TestModule
  def test_method; "ok"; end
end

class A
    def initialize(add_module)
        singleton_class.include(TestModule) if add_module
    end
end

A.new(true).test_method  # module method called
A.new(false).test_method # NoMethodError
```

Note that I changed `display` to `test_method`, because `display` is a built in Kernel method so it won't raise NoMethodError even if you don't include the module on the instance.

Note, Ozer's answer is the same thing but using a different syntax.

-- **edit in response to comment** --

Adding methods on the singleton class takes priority over those added to the regular class, and if you include multiple modules onto the singleton class, the last on will take priority:

```
module A; def fn; 1; end; end
module B; def fn; 2; end; end
module C; def fn; 3; end; end

class D
  include A
  def initialize(add_b, add_c)
    singleton_class.include(B) if add_b
    singleton_class.include(C) if add_c
  end
end

puts D.new(false, false).fn # => 1
puts D.new(true, true).fn   # => 3
```

Comment: thanks, In case of ex: `class A` inheriting properties of another `class B` and `class B` as well contains `test_method`. How is it possible to use the module `TestModule` s `test_method` instead of method inside the `class B`.

Comment: thanks for prompt response. And what is the differences/side-effects in calling methods between including a `module` inside a class: 
1) include `module` outside `initialize`.
2) Include `module` inside `initialize`.

Comment: @ashr81 it's a difference in scope. Think about it this way, in order to add methods to a _single instance_ you need instance to _exist_ which doesn't happen until initialize.

Answer (score 5):

[`include`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-include) adds all the methods from the module to any instances of the class that includes the module. To add the methods to an individual object you can use [`extend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Object.html#method-i-extend):

```
class A
  def initialize(add_module)
    extend(MM::NN) if add_module
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This will add it to just the instance that is being initialized:

```
class A
  def initialize(add_module)
    if add_module
      (class <<self; include MM::NN; end)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What are the parentheses around `class ... end` for?

Answer (score 1):

You could add it to the singleton class as others suggest above. But I would suggest that the fact that OOP constructs are making your task hard is because you are approaching the problem from a bad angle. I think having instances of class `A` behave so differently by having different methods and ancestors is going to cause a lot more confusion than it solves.

What I'd suggest instead is that you try to accomplish what you are doing using composition instead of inheritance. That is, have an instance variable inside `class A` that contains the behavior in the`MM:NN`. This depends on the specifics of the behavior in that module, but could roughly look like this:

```
# This class is here because I'm assuming you can't make `MM::NN` a class in its own right. However it probably needs additional data or methods to actually work with the MM::NN methods
class NN_implementation
  include MM::NN
end

class A
  def initialize(use_module)
    # if this class needs access to data or methods from A, you could add `self` as an input arg to the constructor of `NN_implementation`
    @nn = NN_implmenetation.new if use_module
  end

  def has_nn?
    !@nn.blank?
  end
end
```

Then you can either (1) expose the specific `NN` methods you want as methods on class `A`, or you can expose the `nn` instance var using `attr_reader` and call something like `my_a_instnace.nn.some_nn_method if my_a_instance.has_nn?`. Again, largely depends on the specifics of `A` and `MM::NN` how I would ultimately code this up for prod-ready code, but something along these lines keeps class definitions clean and makes it not confusing where specific behavior comes from.