# What is a singleton class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, eigenclass

I m having trouble understanding the concept of **eigenclass** or **singleton class** in ruby. I read a lot that the eigenclass **is a class's class**. That doesn't make sense to me as for me a class's class is actually `Class` as all classes are actually instances of the class `Class`.

Another thing I don't quite get is the following statement: a class method is actually an instance method of the class eigenclass. The eigenclass is accessible this way :

```
YourClass = Class.new
class << YourClass
  def class_method
  end
end
```

But if the eigenclass is indeed the YourClass class (that is `Class`), shouldn't the preceding piece of code open the class `Class` and add to it the instance method `class_method` making it accessible to all of its future instances (that is any regular class defined in the future)?

I actually kind of feel that the singleton class is not the same as `Class`. When you do :

```
class MyClass
end

MyClass.singleton_class
```

you get `#<Class:MyClass>` which is different from the output of `MyClass.class => Class`

What is that `#<Class:MyClass>` output ? This has nothing to do with namespace as otherwise there would be two: `Class::MyClass`...

I'm Looking for a simple and unambiguous explanation of the eigenclass concept in order to clarify my ideas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is the singleton class in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212407/what-exactly-is-the-singleton-class-in-ruby)

Comment: TBH I dont think I still quite grasp it, from what I read in this answer I would not say that " the eigenclass is a class's class". From that answer, I get that the eigenclass is a special class from an object where methods unique to that object live. I thus understand that every object has 2 different classes : it's classic "class" where all the methods common to all objects of this type live and the eigenclass. Moreover that other answer does not explain the #<Class:MyClass> output...

Comment: If the very old and well-received answers to that question do not answer it for you then you should state in your question that you've read them and that they do not answer your specific question because your specific question is different in ways x,y, and z. Otherwise, your generic question "What is a singleton class in Ruby?" is indeed answered by [What exactly is the singleton class in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/212407/3784008).

Comment: @anothermh To be fair, the answer you cite doesn't really explain what "the singleton class of the object" actually is (I'd say that it is rather a pretty thorough explanation of the role that a singleton class plays), and I believe that that is the thrust of the OP's question. As such, I'm not convinced that this question is a duplicate of the one on which you're basing our vote to close.

Comment: @BobRodes, how would you suggest renaming the title of my question then ? Im open to suggestions !

Comment: A little hard to do! Seems that you're looking for something a bit more specific, though, about what's going on under the hood than the other question is. In particular, something about why Ruby doesn't assign class methods directly to the `Class` class, if the eigenclass is really just a reference to the `Class` object. Perhaps that helps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Singleton classes hold methods that are specific to a single object.

For generic objects, it's a nice-to-have feature. But for classes, it's crucial. Let's start with the objects:

#### Singleton classes for objects

Instance methods are usually defined in classes. All instances of the same class share the same instance methods. The singleton class sits between the object and its class. It allows each instance to have its own set of methods, independent of the other instances.

If we have two classes, `Foo` and `Bar` with 2 instances each `a`, `b` and `c`, `d`:

```
class Foo ; end
class Bar ; end

a = Foo.new #=> #<Foo:0x00007fc280963008>
b = Foo.new #=> #<Foo:0x00007f8319016b18>
c = Bar.new #=> #<Bar:0x00007fa66c8d7290>
d = Bar.new #=> #<Bar:0x00007f94d5106ac8>
```

You would have this class structure: (simplified, excluding modules)

```
object          singleton class              class    superclass   ...

  a ── #<Class:#<Foo:0x00007fc280963008>> ─┐
                                           ├─ Foo ─┐
  b ── #<Class:#<Foo:0x00007f8319016b18>> ─┘       │
                                                   ├─ Object ── BasicObject
  c ── #<Class:#<Bar:0x00007fa66c8d7290>> ─┐       │
                                           ├─ Bar ─┘
  d ── #<Class:#<Bar:0x00007f94d5106ac8>> ─┘
```

Ruby creates those singleton classes lazily, for example when calling `singleton_class`.

So when defining a method `a.hello`, it is not stored in `a`'s class `Foo`, but in `a`'s singleton class:

```
def a.hello
  'hello from a'
end

a.method(:hello).owner
#=> #<Class:#<Foo:0x00007fc280963008>>  <-- a's singleton class
```

Because of that, `b` doesn't see that method, even though both are `Foo` instances:

```
b.hello #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `hello'
```

And we can even define a method with the same name for `b` without interfering with `a`:

```
def b.hello
  'hello from b'
end

b.method(:hello).owner
#=> #<Class:#<Foo:0x00007f8319016b18>>  <-- b's singleton class

a.hello #=> "hello from a"
b.hello #=> "hello from b"
```

We could also define a generic `hello` in `Foo` and override it on a per instance level: (you usually don't do that, but it's possible)

```
class Foo
  def hello
    'hello'
  end
end

def a.hello
  "#{super} from a"
end

def b.hello
  "b says #{super.upcase}!"
end

a.hello #=> "hello from a"
b.hello #=> "b says HELLO!"

c = Foo.new
c.hello #=> "hello"
```

#### Singleton classes for classes

The above is especially important for classes. Each class is an instance of `Class`:

```
Foo.class #=> Class
```

Let's say we wanted to have a method `Foo.hello`, where would we define it?

Instance methods are usually defined in the instance's class, so we *could* define it in `Foo`'s class:

```
class Class
  def hello
    'Hello from Foo'
  end
end

Foo.hello
#=> "Hello from Foo"
```

But that would make the method available to all instances of `Class`:

```
Bar.hello
#=> "Hello from Foo"

String.hello
#=> "Hello from Foo"
```

It would be better to have a place that's exclusive to the `Foo` instance. And that place is `Foo`'s singleton class:

```
def Foo.hello
  'Hello from Foo'
end
```

or

```
class Foo
  def self.hello       # <-- self is Foo, so this is just "def Foo.hello"
    'hello from Foo'
  end
end
```

Just like `a.hello` above, this method is only available to `Foo`:

```
Foo.hello #=> "hello from Foo"
Bar.hello #=> NoMethodError
```

We call these methods *class methods*, but they are really just instance methods of the singleton class:

```
Foo.method(:hello).owner
#=> #<Class:Foo>   <-- Foo's singleton class

Foo.method(:hello).unbind == Foo.singleton_class.instance_method(:hello)
#=> true
```

And if you compare the singleton methods for classes with those for objects, you'll see that they are identical. That's because in Ruby, classes are objects too, and all objects work alike.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting a bit off track by confusing the idea of the eigenclass with the idea of a Ruby class instance. They aren't exactly the same; it's more correct to say that Ruby implements class definitions internally as two objects.

This is easily enough demonstrated:

```
$ irb
> ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_CLASS]
 => 1285 
> Foo = Class.new { def instance_method; end }
 => Foo 
> ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_CLASS]
 => 1287
```

Internally, every object has a `klass` pointer, which on the surface points to the class the object is an instance of. However, every object (except certain primitives such as `Integer`, `Float` and `Symbol`) also has an eigenclass instance, and this is what the `klass` pointer actually points to. In the case of classes, then, the `klass` pointer doesn't actually point to the `Class` class, but to the singleton object that's part of the class definition, and that contains the method table that holds the class methods.

As the link that anothermh provides explains, the "ordinary" class object's method table contains all the class's instance methods, while the eigenclass object's method table contains all of the class's class methods. This is the mechanism that prevents all of the class's class methods from being accessible to any instance of the `Class` class.

Now, the eigenclass (*eigen* is German for "own" in the sense of "my own") is the class of the class, which is why it's also called a *metaclass*. (Have a look at the source code for `Class::new` and you will see a call to `rb_make_metaclass`.)

This is why a call to `MyClass.singleton_class` returns `#Class:MyClass` rather than `Class` as a call to `MyClass.class` does. This syntax is analogous to `p Foo.new` returning something like `#<Foo:0x00007f9c0d190400>`, which is the class and the pointer to the instance. With `#Class:MyClass`, `MyClass` is the pointer to the instance. So, this describes a reference to `MyClass`'s metaclass, or the class of `MyClass`. This is not to be confused with what class `MyClass` is an instance of, which, of course, is `Class`.

In case you're curious, the `klass` pointer in the eigenclass instance actually points to itself. This is demonstrated by the fact that `MyClass.singleton_class.singleton_class` returns `#Class:#Class:MyClass`.

For a more comprehensive overview, see [Demystifying Ruby Singleton Classes](http://leohetsch.com/demystifying-ruby-singleton-classes/). For a look at what's going on in the source code, see [The Ruby Hacking Guide: Chapter 4](https://ruby-hacking-guide.github.io/class.html). Finally, [Ruby Under a Microscope](http://patshaughnessy.net/ruby-under-a-microscope) is an excellent resource for a comprehensive deep dive into Ruby internals.

[Edited to incorporate some of the discussion in comments]

Comment: "However, if the object is a class definition, the `klass` pointer points not to the `Class` class, but to the eigenclass instance." – Actually, that is true for *all* objects. Some Ruby implementations may, as a private internal optimization, only actually create the singleton class lazily when it is really needed, but *conceptually* and *semantically*, the `klass` of *every object* is *always* its singleton class.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That's very interesting. I had the feeling that that was true, but couldn't quite dig up anything that would get me to the point where I was sure of it. Can you point me to some resource that spells that out, or perhaps suggest where I can find the relevant source code?

Comment: Well, you can easily check that something like `obj = Object.new; def obj.bar; end; obj.bar; obj2 = Object.new; obj2.bar # NoMethodError` works for all objects. There is no place for method `obj.bar` to live than in `obj`'s singleton class. (Actually, there are a few objects that can't have singleton methods, like `Symbol`s, `Float`s, and `Integer`s. The *real* reason is that they are not implemented as objects in the runtime, and thus don't even have a class, let alone a singleton class. But for our semantic model, we can still pretend they have a singleton class that is frozen.)

Comment: `#Class:MyClass` is not the same as `#Class:#Class:MyClass`. The former is the singleton class of `MyClass` whereas the latter is the singleton class of the singleton class. (hence the different output)

Comment: @Stefan I agree with your like comment thus the sentence. Thus the sentence " the klass pointer in the eigenclass instance actually points to itself. This is demonstrated by the fact that MyClass.singleton_class.singleton_class returns #Class:#Class:MyClass." seems to be incorrect.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I get from "Ruby Under a Microscope" that some of the simple objects aren't really objects at all, because their values are saved in the `VALUE` value that normally contains a pointer value to an `RObject` structure or some generic object structure such as `RArray`. What I don't get from there is that `klass` pointers always point to a singleton – most of its diagrams have `klass` pointing directly to `Class`. It would seem that this is misleading. Using your example, `obj.singleton_methods` includes `:bar`, which strongly suggests a method table in the singleton class.

Comment: @Stefan Umm...right? Exactly the point I was trying to make? The class of the singleton class of the class is the singleton class.

Comment: @DavidGeismar I dunno. Seems to me to be correct. If `x = Foo.new`, inspecting `x` reveals something like `#<Foo:0x00007feaa2169010>`. `ClassType:PointerValue`, in other words. Similarly, `#Class:MyClass` says that an object of type `Class` points to `MyClass`. In other words, the class of `MyClass`. As such, `#Class:Class:MyClass` means an object of type `Class` that also points to the class of `MyClass`. Which is how I conclude that the `klass` pointer in the eigenclass points to itself. What refutes this position in your mind?

Comment: @BobRodes to me, the _"points to itself"_ part sounds as if `MyClass.singleton_class` and  `MyClass.singleton_class.singleton_class` should return the same object. Maybe I misunderstand that sentence. Could you clarify it?

Comment: @Stefan I suppose there is room for different interpretations. As I see it, though, the syntax is `ClassType:InstancePointer`. So `MyClass.singleton_type` is a pointer of type `Class` that points to the instance `MyClass`. `MyClass.singleton_type.singleton_type` is a pointer of type `Class` that points to the instance `Class:MyClass`, which, of course, is a pointer of type `Class` that points to the instance `MyClass`. In other words, the same instance. *Et cetera ad infinitum*.

Answer (score 0):

*Eigenclass* is no longer a name used in the Ruby world because Ruby officially introduced a method `Object#singleton_class` in I don't know which version (sorry).

Every object in Ruby, being a "normal" object or a class, or even a singleton class, has its own singleton class.

A singleton class is a class.

```
Object.new.singleton_class.is_a?(Class)  #=> true
```

A singleton class has and only has one instance, and it's the object you call `singleton_class` on. e.g. the only instance of `foo.singleton_class` is `foo`.

Ruby allows you to add methods to individual objects.

```
a = Object.new
b = Object.new

def a.foo
  'foo'
end

a.foo  #=> "foo"
b.foo  #=> raises NoMethodError
```

But all instance methods should be defined in a class, so in which class is `a.foo` defined? The answer is `a.singleton_class`. Because `a.singleton_class` only has one instance that is `a`, the instance method `foo` can only be called on `a`, not on `b`, though they are of the same type.

As for the class's singleton classes, their purpose is to store the "normal classes'" class methods, or if you twist your brain a little, the instance methods that are bound to the individual class instances.

Don't you feel Ruby's object model consistent and beautiful?