# Include different module into same class based on use case

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.5

If there are 2 modules - module `Abc` and module `Bcd` and one class - class `Efg`.

Now we want to include module `Abc` into class `Efg` in once instance and need to include module `Bcd` into class Efg in another instance but not both modules at same time.

Is it possible to do in Ruby classes?

Comment: What do you mean by _instance_ in your question? I.e. at what time should the decision be taken, which class is going to be included?

Comment: Why do you specifically want an answer for a no-longer-supported version of Ruby on Rails? What makes you think this answer is specific to Rails and moreover to a specific version of Rails that is over 7 years old?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your question properly then I think you can use [singleton_class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212407/what-exactly-is-the-singleton-class-in-ruby) to include a module only for a specific *instance* of a class:

```
inst1 = Efg.new
inst2 = Efg.new
inst3 = Efg.new

inst1.singleton_class.include Asd
inst2.singleton_class.include Bcd
```

Now `inst1` will have the methods from `Asd` and `inst2` will have the methods from `Bcd`. `inst3` will have none of the methods.