# Can't pass my hash as an argument to the class constructor

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create dynamic methods for a class so that the methods are hash key names using define_method. Can anyone suggest why I can't pass my hash as an argument to the class constructor? When I check through pry the @my_hsh variable I get nil. Why am I getting nil and not my hash?
When I run this code, I have an error that that nil does not have an each method

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'pry'

class Foo
  def initialize(my_hsh = {})
    @my_hsh = my_hsh
  end
  
  @my_hsh.each do |k, v|
    define_method k do
      v
    end
  end
end

hsh = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
}
my_foo = Foo.new(hsh)
my_foo.first
my_foo.second
```

Comment: It looks like the hash iteration is not happening within the `initialize` method. You may also want to use `define_singleton_method` there instead as the methods defined will vary based on the hash passed to the instance.

Comment: The 1st `@my_hsh` within `initialize` is an instance variable whereas the 2nd `@my_hsh` in the class body is a class instance variable. Instance and class are different objects with their own set of instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

@my_hsh is nil because it is being called before the `initialize` method is run.

`@my_hsh = my_hsh` is run when the object is initialised

the `@my_hash.each` loop is being called when the class is being initialialised, which is before `Foo.new` is called.

To make this work you would need to create a method on the Foo class itself then call that method against the food class.

e.g.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Foo
  def self.define_methods(hash)
    hash.each do |k, v|
      define_method k do
        v
      end
    end
  end
end

hsh = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
}

Foo.define_methods(hsh)
my_foo = Foo.new
puts my_foo.first
puts my_foo.second
```

If you really want to define the methods on instantiation you could do it 2 ways

1. Add the methods to the class on object instantiation

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Foo
  def initialize(my_hsh = {})
    my_hsh.each do |k, v|
      self.class.define_method k do
        v
      end
    end
  end
end


hsh = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
}
my_foo = Foo.new(hsh)
puts my_foo.first
puts my_foo.second
```

this is not ideal, because if you create a second instance it will affect the first instance

e.g.

```
class Foo
  def initialize(my_hsh = {})
    my_hsh.each do |k, v|
      self.class.define_method k do
        v
      end
    end
  end
end


hsh = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
}
hsh2 = {
  first: 3,
  second: 4,
}
my_foo = Foo.new(hsh)
Foo.new(hsh2)
puts my_foo.first # 3
puts my_foo.second # 4
```

alternatively you could make the methods dynamic by using [method_missing](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing)

```
class Foo
  def initialize(my_hsh = {})
    @hsh = my_hsh
  end

  def method_missing(method)
    @hsh[method] or raise NoMethodError.new("Method `#{method}` doesn't exist.")
  end
end


hsh = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
}
hsh2 = {
  first: 3,
  second: 4,
}
my_foo = Foo.new(hsh)
Foo.new(hsh2)
puts my_foo.first # 1
puts my_foo.second # 2
puts my_foo.three # NoMethodError raised
```

Comment: "@my_hsh is nil because it is being called before the initialize method is run." – This is wrong. The problem is simply that the OP is setting the instance variable on one object, then trying to read it from a completely different object.

Comment: i already did this task with method_missing, but I would like to understand why this code does not work. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could check singleton methods: [What exactly is the singleton class in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212407/what-exactly-is-the-singleton-class-in-ruby) **and if it fits for you**, you can implement in this way.

Note that the loop for method definition needs to be wrapped up in another method and called this is an example:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(my_hsh = {})
    @my_hsh = my_hsh
    self.define_methods_from_hash
  end
  
  def define_methods_from_hash
    @my_hsh.each do |k, v|
      define_singleton_method k do
        v
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you can check if it works:

```
hsh = {
  first: 1,
  second: 2,
}
my_foo = Foo.new(hsh)
p my_foo.first #=> 1
p my_foo.second #=> 2
p my_foo.singleton_methods #=> [:second, :first]
```

While without passing any hash:

```
my_foo_2 = Foo.new() # default empty hash
p my_foo_2.singleton_methods #=> []
```

Answer (score 0):

*Why am I getting nil and not my hash?*

In your class definition, you have two different variables @my_hsh : The one in the initializer pretains to the instance of your class. The one written a bit below belongs to the class itself. You try it in irb with this example:

```
 class C; @x=5; def initialize; @x=13; end; def f; @x; end; def self.g; @x; end; end
```

If you now request the value of `C.new.f`, you get 13, but if you request `C.g`, you get 5.

I always try to name class and instance variables differently, even though it is not required; having the same name just leads to confusion and errors.